# Is there a way to obtain envs from the workflow object?

Tags: github-api

I have the following

```
name: 'test'
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  ANKA_TEMPLATE_ID: "91554c0a-8f10-44d6-a4cd-e20f7035d350"

jobs:
  test:
. . .
```

I then query run the workflow, query the API for workflows, and get the workflow using the ID. However, I don't see the `env`s anywhere in the API responses. Is it possible to obtain these from the API?